# Angular - Convert objects in a nested array into comma seapared values before binding to grid

Tags: arrays, json, angular

below is part of my JSON response coming from an API

```
    {
        "totalCount": 2,
        "customAttributes": [
            {
                "objectType": "OWNER",
                "atrributeId": 215,
                "attributeName": "DATELICENSEFIRSTISSUED",
                "attributeDisplayName": "DATE LICENSE FIRST ISSUED",
                "dataType": "DATE",
                "inputValues": [],
                "isGridEligible": "true",
                "isInvoiceEligible": "false"
            },
            {
                "objectType": "LOCATION",
                "atrributeId": 217,
                "attributeName": "DONOTRENEW",
                "attributeDisplayName": "DO NOT RENEWS",
                "dataType": "Value List",
                "inputValues": [
                    {
                        "id": 5,
                        "value": "VEHICLELISTREQUIRED"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 6,
                        "value": "STATESWITHRECIPROCITY"
                    }
                ],
                "isGridEligible": "true",
                "isInvoiceEligible": "false"
            }        
        ]
    }
```

Here, I am binding `customAttributes` as grid data.

```
    this.customFieldsService.getCustomFields(this.columnList, this.pageNumber, this.pageSize, null).subscribe(res => {
      if(res){
        this.cfData = res;    
        this.gridData = {
            data: this.cfData.customAttributes,
            total: this.cfData.totalCount
        }
      }      
    });
```

Here, my problem is with `inputValues` column, which comes as an array of objects. I need to convert it to comma seaparated values and then bind to grid data like

```
  "inputValues": ["VEHICLELISTREQUIRED" "STATESWITHRECIPROCITY"]
```

I can ignore the "id" property as we are not using it at angular side. I tried using `join` method but not able to solve it within the nested array. Please suggest. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In typescript it can be done with:

```
const joined: string = customAttribute.inputValues
    .map(x => x.value)           //  [{value: 'VEHICLELISTREQUIRED'}, {value: 'STATESWITHRECIPROCITY'}]
    .join(' ')                   //  "VEHICLELISTREQUIRED" "STATESWITHRECIPROCITY"
 const putIntoArray = [joined];  // ["VEHICLELISTREQUIRED" "STATESWITHRECIPROCITY"]
```

Of course you can put the joined string immediately into an array.